# Laravel communicating with a separated REST-API

Tags: php, api, rest, laravel

I've got a REST-API made in flask (python) for my mobile app. But, know we wanted to do the web app, so and we'll do it in PHP. Everyone recommends us to use Laravel, but, they say that it's a framework that is strong if you use it completely (this includes the ORM).
For someone who used it before: Is that true? Shall we use another framework in order to make the app web because its an overkill using Laravel? Or there's a good way to use laravel without communicating directly with a database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are free to choose what use in Laravel, if you don't want to use Eloquent(ORM) you can do it. And Laravel still will be cool.

Comment: You don't *need* to use Eloquent, or any other parts of Laravel for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an API why don't use angular, emberjs or vuejs?

You can use Laravel to connect to the API database or make http_request to the python API in the Laravel controller.

All options are valid.

Comment: It's not that I don't like those .js frameworks. But there're people in my team that are fluent with PHP.

Comment: In this case try to use Laravel with GuzzleHttp\Client to make calls to your Python api and render the result in the blade template system.